# How to consolidate an array of multiple objects into single object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

So, I have an array like this:

```
[
  { tags__region: "Stockholm" },
  { tags__region: "Lund" },
  { tags__region: "Mora" },
  { tags__user: "Johan" },
  { tags__user: "Eva" }
]
```

and I want to turn that into an object like this:

```
{
  tags__region: ["Stockholm", "Lund", "Mora"], 
  tags__user: ["Johan", "Eva"]
}
```

Is there a way with lodash?
Are vanilla Array/Object -methods simple enough?

Keep in mind the keys on my array are unknown, so they are not always the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Javascript.

```js
let arr = [{
    tags__region: "Stockholm"
  },
  {
    tags__region: "Lund"
  },
  {
    tags__region: "Mora"
  },
  {
    tags__user: "Johan"
  },
  {
    tags__user: "Eva"
  }
];

arr = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {

  let key = Object.keys(val)[0];
  let value = Object.values(val)[0];
  acc[key] =  acc[key] ? [...acc[key],value] : [value]
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Beautiful! (unfortunately I'm too new here to up your answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lodash's `_.mergeWith()` with array spread to combine all items in the array to a single object. If the same property exists in two object, the values will be collected to an array:

```js
const arr = [{"tags__region":"Stockholm"},{"tags__region":"Lund"},{"tags__region":"Mora"},{"tags__user":"Johan"},{"tags__user":"Eva"}]

const result = _.mergeWith({}, ...arr, (objValue = [], srcValue) => 
  [...objValue, srcValue]
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

With Lodash/fp you can generate a function (`fn`) using `_.mergeAllWith()`, and `_.concat()` that will do the same thing:

```js
const fn = _.mergeAllWith(_.concat)

const arr = [{"tags__region":"Stockholm"},{"tags__region":"Lund"},{"tags__region":"Mora"},{"tags__user":"Johan"},{"tags__user":"Eva"}]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you that's neat as well